# After including bootstrap icons get weird underline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I recently included bootstrap in my project for multiple features that I require, however its inclusion caused this strange line to appear underneath icons in my main menu which was not there before. I have been searching for a while now and honestly have no good leads. The problem looks like this: (occurs on hover over the icon)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru4RN.png)

The code for this looks like so

`<a id="link-groups-icon" href="#link-groups" class="nav-a"><i class="icon-link"><span class="icon-label-small">Scenes</span></i></a>`

I've tried taking out the  thinking that it had something to do with the label...however that didn't lead to any progress.

Anyone have any weird problems like this after including bootstrap or have any educated guesses as to where I might dig in order to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using developer tools in your browser to inspect the element and see what styles are being applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a rule to the anchor tag -- it looks to me, at least by the image and without having real code to inspect, that the default behavior of text-underline is being applied. Negate it with something like this:
`#link-groups-icon{text-decoration:none;}`

A code inspector would tell you quickly what's going wrong.

Best of luck!